# Struggling to solve "ApolloProvider was not pased a client instance."

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I have read multiple articles and items trying to solve this problem. I think I have a problem with the way that I have formatted my code but cannot figure out where the error is located. I am currently just trying to get anything to pass onto the page so I can start formatting the site.

This is the code that I have for the page, please let me know if I need to add another files code:

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './pages/Home'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import Header from './components/Header'


function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<Home />}
            />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
const root = createRoot(rootElement)

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13"
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <main> 
            <p>This is the home page! Hello </p>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Here is the error that I am receiving:

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: I tried to get the screenshot to post but it inserted it as a link instead of showing the screenshot.

Comment: To show an image add `!` before the link, this is how you put images in Markdown which is used by StackOverflow. You can also use image upload and it will create the proper image automatically.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/) you need to create a client that will point to the GraphQL server:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://flyby-router-demo.herokuapp.com/',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<Home />}
            />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That worked perfectly. I am still trying to fully understand the documentation.